# Regular expression for positive integers, 2 to 4 digits but no 00, 000 or 0000

Tags: regex

I would like to use regular expression to match only positive integers at least 2 but no more than 4 digits. I know that I can do that with this regex: ^\d{2,4}$

Now, I want to exclude 00, 000, 0000 and also leading zeros such as 02, 003, 0001. Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `00000` and so on?

Comment: @hwnd I want up to 4 digits. Thanks

Comment: What about any leading zeros?  Like 0001, 001, or 01?

Comment: No i dont want leading zeros. Thank you @Shar1er80 for the comment.

Comment: `At least 2 but not more than 4 digits` -> I'm voting to reopen this question as not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

`^[1-9]\d{1,3}$`

The first part, [1-9] makes sure the first digit is not a 0, after that, any digits can follow, up to a maximum of 4 in total.

Comment: Thank you very much this seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can impose restrictions using a lookahead anchored at the beginning:

```
^(?!0+)\d{2,4}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kO0uS4/3)

The negative lookahead `(?!0+)` checks at the beginning of a string (as it is located right after the `^` anchor) if there are any 1 or more zeros (with `0+`).

Comment: Thank you very much but this allows leading zeros.

Comment: Now it does not, I removed the end of line anchor.

Comment: Sorry you are right. Thank you very much.